# Golang HTTP Route Handler Generic Wrapper Implementation

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert a route handler which returns response body and error instead of directly writing it to response writer. 
Then I want to send success/error response from the wrapper function instead.

It'll help me add tracing and metrics in a common place for all routes.

To achieve that, I tried this:

```
router.HandleFunc(app, "/login", WrapHandler(Login)).Methods("POST")
```

```
func WrapHandler(handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) (interface{}, *types.HandlerErrorResponse)) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        response, errResponse := handler(w, r)

        sendResponse(r.Context(), w, response, errResponse)
    }
}
```

Login is an interface with signature:

```
Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*AuthenticationResponse, *types.HandlerErrorResponse)
```

Now, with this code the error comes in compilation:

```sh
cannot use Login (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) (*AuthenticationResponse, *types.HandlerErrorResponse)) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) (interface {}, *types.HandlerErrorResponse) in argument to WrapHandlerNew
```

But, to make generic Wrapper, I have to make my response body as interface.

Please let me know, how can I achieve it.

Comment: What if you change the `Login` signature to return `interface{}`?

Comment: @bereal That I can do, infact, that's what I'm doing for now. But, in this case, I'll lose type checks for handler return data.
That I think will create problems in longer term for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it compile 
`Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*AuthenticationResponse, *types.HandlerErrorResponse)` needs to be `Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, *types.HandlerErrorResponse)`

However I'd suggest you to define an inteface ( or use an existing one : `io.Reader` might be what you want )

Define the methods you need to access from the response and then return that.

```
type GenericBody interface{
    Bytes() []byte
}
```

Now as long as your return object implements this method, you can return it. However, the function signature will have to include this new type.